# Sort by values and get position in list

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to make sort a list from "highest value" to "lowest value" of values below for $rank['workouts']; and then compared to $personal['workouts'] get to know which position $personal['workouts'] have in this list.

I.e. if `$rank['workouts'];` is equal to 3,6,2

And `$personal['workouts'];` is equal to 7

Then I want to list this as: 7,6,3,2 which gives me a position of 1 in this rank.

Any suggestions how this could be done?

I have this code:

```
                    while ($rank = mysql_fetch_array($get_rank)) {

                        echo $rank['workouts'];
                        }      
                        echo $personal['workouts'];
```

Comment: `array_merge` then `sort`.

Comment: Okey! How do these functions work in this case? array_merge then sort?

Comment: First you merge all **workouts** values, then `sort` the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rank['workouts']=array(3,2,6);    //your array
$personal['workouts'] = array(7);  // next array 
$merge = array_merge($personal['workouts'], $rank['workouts']);  // merge two arrays in $merge
rsort($merge); // Sort the array in reverse
foreach($merge as $key ) {
    echo "$key".',';   //print the array
}
```